How to make sure a service, that may or may not exist/be loaded, is stoped?
I am trying to port a script that have the very banal and common use case: pkill -SIGTERM -eF some_pid_file
very simple case: Pid file exist? Pid exist? kill it. If pid is present and we failed to kill the process, an error code. everything else, success.
with systemd i cannot get a reliable way to have an error code only in the case where stopping a running service fail. It will fail if the service is not set. even the means to detect if service is active will fail if it is not present, just a different error code.
systemctl --user is-active will return 2 if not active, 4 if non existent. Only way to not get an error is if it is actually running.
systemctl --user stop will return 5 if there's no service installed.
Basically i'm looking for something that behave like stop but that doesn't fail only if it is already not loaded/running.


systemctl --user is-active will return 2 if not active, 4 if non existent. Only way to not get an error is if it is actually running.

That's fine: all those values imply that the service is not active, so you can use a single if to cover all such situations.
if systemctl --user --quiet is-active "$svc"; then
    systemctl --user stop "$svc"
fi

Also, there's a reason those are all distinct return values – so that you could check for them individually and decide through your code whether each of those results is a "success" or truly an "error". For example, if you wanted to treat 'no such service' as a success:
stop_service() {
    local svc=$1
    systemctl --user stop "$svc" || (( $? == 5 ))
}

Of course, this is not a good example, since you still get an error message that's difficult to suppress individually, but the point is about the ability to check $?.
